# what is general route rules in i18n

Tags: internationalization

I would like to separate my website to follow the `Accept-Languages`.

I have 4 language strings `en`, `en-CA`, `zh-HK` and `zh-TW`.

And my plan is routing them like `/en`, `/en-CA`, `/zh-HK` and `/zh-TW`.

but I have a question about that.

what is the general rule about routing?

for example, when I visit `AWS` website with `/en-CA`, I see `404 Not Found`.
but I visit `AWS` with `/ca`, I can touch them.

Why `AWS` doesn't support `/en-CA`? or why it uses only `/ca` not both.

If there are some rules or protocol, let me know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand. Accept-Languages has nothing to do with URL structure. If you want en/ you should deliver files from there 9and maybe just Accept-Languages: en for files in en/. So, you are asking how to route (redirect?) at webserver or at javascript level? Or what?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I know I can route with any characters. I just want to know the standard guideline for routing. e.g Taiwan `/tw`, Canada `/ca`, United Kingdom `/gb`

Comment: as far I know, there is no standard way. Your proposal is used in Europe. I think for AWS, `ca` is just the country, when some services need to be tailored (and possibly language is chosen in an other way). Which I like (but not often used), so e.g. I must read page on a national language, and not English, or I should choose en_GB. So it is much more a design decision, than a technical (and standardized way).